# jquery select along with this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my HTML like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>12AM</option>
                <option>11PM</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>12AM</option>
                <option>11PM</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to assign an id attribute to select tag inside each tr. The following jquery does not seem to work

```
function addRow()
{
    var rowCount = 0;
    $('#SHourDivTable tr').each(function() {
        if(rowCount != 0)
        {
            console.log($(this).html());
            $(this).add("select:eq(0)").attr("id", rowCount);
            $(this).add("select:eq(1)").attr("id", rowCount);
        }
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    });
}
```

When i run this, the id attribute gets assigned to tr rather than select tag.

Comment: IDs have to be unique!

Comment: Your HTML does not appear to contain any DOM objects with `id=SHourDivTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the id 1,2 to your select elements. You had an extra  in your mark up also remember that ids must be unique! id's 1 and 2 are also bad ids - select1, select2 etc would be better.

I added the id *SHourDivTable*  to your table as  I believe that was your intention.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgGs7/4/)

```
$('#SHourDivTable tr select').each(function(i,select) {
    $(select).attr('id','select'+i);
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, worked like charm. Yes, i meant to keep ids unique and also table has id as SHourDivTable, did not edit the xml before pasting it here. Also what is the issue with $(this).add("select:eq(0)"), this should ideally take me to first select tag right?

Answer (score 2):

IDs **must be unique**. They also **shouldn't start with a number**. You should use `data` attributes to do that.

I've also used `table` instead of `#SHourDivTable`, as I can't see a table with that ID in your markup.

Lastly, you need `find` **not** `add` for what you're doing here.

Try this:

```
function addRow()
{
    var rowCount = 0;
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        if(rowCount != 0)
        {
            $(this).find("select:eq(0)").data("rowNumber", rowCount);
            $(this).find("select:eq(1)").data("rowNumber", rowCount);
        }
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    });
}
```